# Magento2 : Module and theme not working together

Tags: magento2

I have purchased a **theme** and a **module**, but after installing both modules is not working. I am tow in Magento and don't know how to detect the issue. Module "catelog_product_view.xml" code is like below,

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
        <block class="FME\Pricecalculator\Block\Product\Pricecalculator" name="fme.pricecalculator" template="FME_Pricecalculator::pricecalculator.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Is it overwriting the method or function? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain what "No working" means? the xml you provided should add a block in the product info options section on the product list page.

Comment: Please contact module and theme support , if you purchased